# ASP.NET Core - Use of Interfaces and Services to properly manage resources

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, interface

Let's consider this example of a rest web service:

**Controller.cs**

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("/getRedProduct")]
        public async Task<ProductResponse> GetRedProduct(Payload payload)
        {           
            return await new MakeRedProduct().make(payload);
        }

  [HttpPost]
        [Route("/getBlueProduct")]
        public async Task<ProductResponse> GetBlueProduct(Payload payload)
        {           
            return await new MakeBlueProduct().make(payload);
        }
```

I was told this implementation is incorrect because multiple instances of MakeRedProduct() and MakeBlueProduct() will be created each time the web services are called, taking up all the server RAM and crashing the application.

Instead, he suggested me to do the following:

**IMakeProducts.cs**

```
public interface MakeProducts
    {
public Task<ProductResponse> makeRed(Payload payload);
public Task<ProductResponse> makeYellow(Payload payload);
public Task<ProductResponse> makeYellow(Payload payload);  
    }
```

**MakeProductsService.cs**

```
public class MakeProductsService: IMakeProducts, IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public Task makeRed(Payload payload)
        {
            //code for making red product...
        }
   public Task makeBlue(Payload payload)
        {
            //code for making blue product...
        }
       public Task makeYellow(Payload payload)
        {
            //code for making yellow product...
        }
  
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
 private readonly IMakeProducts _makeProducts;

public Controller(IMakeProducts iMakeProducts )
{          
    _makeProducts= iMakeProducts;
}

 [HttpPost]
    [Route("/getRedProduct")]
    public async Task<ProductResponse> GetRedProduct(Payload payload)
    {       
        return await _makeProducts.makeRed(request);
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMakeProducts, MakeProductsService();
```

This works fine, but something doesn't smell right. Being forced to cram all methods to make every existing product on MakeProductsService.cs create an unmaintainable 1000-line class!

Any clue of what I'm getting wrong will be very appreciated.

Comment: Hi, why are you not using an enum for your color in MakeProductsService.cs, create a generic class method and make one method usable.

Comment: Crashing the app would be an overstatement, but taking up memory is real. But still, it was good advice. You don't want to deal with creating the service on your own, when you can enjoy the benefits of using the built-in [dependency injection mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). And if you feel your services are getting too big and in the result unmaintainable (as you observed), split them into smaller ones, encapsulating parts responsible for a single thing.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Rajat Jha and Prolog. I will use Rajat's advice to try to reduce the overall method count. Proloj's link is the best and most straightforward explanation for Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core, very recommended.

Comment: Just a last question: Making [one interface <----> one service <---> one method] for each one of my endpoints would be acceptable? Or by definition, should a service group have more than 1 method inside?

Comment: In reagards of design, it doesn't make sense when there will be one method within one interface. Let's imagine, you have 500 methods! Rather than this, you should segregate your `interface/service/method` by it responsibility. Similar kind of responsibility should be within one `interface`. This is what [`repository pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) or other [`design pattern`](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns) tell us.